# jax-rs exception mapper implementation issues

Tags: exception, jersey, mapping, jax-rs

I'm trying to implement a web service using `Jersey 2.22.2` and `Jetty 9.1.1.v20140108` with exception mapping. The following class represents an Exception class with Mapper implemented.

```
    @Provider
    public class NotFoundException extends Exception implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NotFoundException() {
    }

    public NotFoundException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException e) {
        Status status = Status.NOT_FOUND;
        ErrorWrapper errorWrapper = new ErrorWrapper();
        errorWrapper.setStatusCode(status.getStatusCode());
        errorWrapper.setTitle(status.getReasonPhrase());
        errorWrapper.setErrorMessage("The resource you're looking for cannot be found.");
        errorWrapper.setApiPath(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().getPath());
        return Response.status(status).entity(errorWrapper).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

To test, whether this is working or not, I created an endpoint that simply throws the above exception, like this:

```
@GET
@Path("test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response test() throws NotFoundException {
    throw new NotFoundException();
}
```

Calling this endpoint returns a `JSON`, like this:

```
{
"statusCode": 404,
"title": "Not Found",
"errorMessage": "The resource you're looking for cannot be found.",
"apiPath": "/users/test"
}
```

From that, I kinda safely assumed that the exception mapping is working.

Now, what I'm trying to do is to throw this exception, if `DAO` method returns a `null` object, for example when trying to fetch a database row that doesn't exist yet. Following are my implementation attempts:

DAO:

```
public User getUserById(Integer id) throws NotFoundException {
        try (DSLContext ctx = new DSLContextFactory("iotrest")
                .getDSLContext(getDbDataSource("iotrest"))) {
            User user = queries.getUserById(ctx, id)
                    .fetchOne()
                    .into(User.class);
            if (user == null
                    || user.getId() == null) {
                throw new NotFoundException("User with id " + id + " not found");
            }
            UserAccessRights userAccessRights = queries.getUserAccessRights(ctx, user.getId())
                    .fetchOne()
                    .into(UserAccessRights.class);
            if (userAccessRights == null) {
                throw new NotFoundException("Access rights not found for user id " + id);
            }
            setUserAccessRights(user, userAccessRights);
            return user;
        }
    }
```

Service:

```
public User getUserById(Integer id) throws NotFoundException {
    return userDao.getUserById(id);
}
```

Resource:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getUserById(@PathParam("id") Integer id) throws NotFoundException {
    User user = new UserService().getUserById(id);        
    return Response.ok(user).build();
}
```

But, when I call the endpoint using an id that doesn't exist yet(2), and get a `NullPointerException`, I'm still getting a `HTTP 500 Request Failed` from Jetty, instead of 404 from `NotFoundException`, like this:

```
    <html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Error 500 </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /users/2. Reason:
        <pre>    Request failed.</pre>
    </p>
    <hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>

</html>
```

Could really use some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not throwing the NotFoundException.
Your code is throwing a NullPointerException.

```
public User getUserById(Integer id) throws NotFoundException {
        try (DSLContext ctx = new DSLContextFactory("iotrest")
                .getDSLContext(getDbDataSource("iotrest"))) {
            User user = queries.getUserById(ctx, id)
         //The NullPointerException is coming from the following line
                    .fetchOne()
                    .into(User.class);
            if (user == null
                    || user.getId() == null) {
                throw new NotFoundException("User with id " + id + " not found");
            }
            UserAccessRights userAccessRights = queries.getUserAccessRights(ctx, user.getId())
                    .fetchOne()
                    .into(UserAccessRights.class);
            if (userAccessRights == null) {
                throw new NotFoundException("Access rights not found for user id " + id);
            }
            setUserAccessRights(user, userAccessRights);
            return user;
        }
    }
```

You need to change your code to something like this:

```
public User getUserById(Integer id) throws NotFoundException {
        try (DSLContext ctx = new DSLContextFactory("iotrest")
                .getDSLContext(getDbDataSource("iotrest"))) {
            User user = queries.getUserById(ctx, id);
             if (user == null
                       || user.getId() == null) {
                    throw new NotFoundException("User with id " + id + " not found");
            }
            user.fetchOne()
                .into(User.class);

            }
            UserAccessRights userAccessRights = queries.getUserAccessRights(ctx, user.getId())
                    .fetchOne()
                    .into(UserAccessRights.class);
            if (userAccessRights == null) {
                throw new NotFoundException("Access rights not found for user id " + id);
            }
            setUserAccessRights(user, userAccessRights);
            return user;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did the modification you suggested, but that didn't help at all. I'm still getting the `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score -1):

`@galusben`'s suggestion was instrumental in finding the solution. Clearly, this line was throwing a NPE.

```
User user = queries.getUserById(ctx, id)
                .fetchOne()
                .into(User.class);
```

So, basically what I did was, before lodging the resultset in `User`, I checked whether the record itself existed or not in the table, like this.

```
UsersRecord usersRecord = queries.getUserById(ctx, id).fetchOne();
```

Then, did a null check on that object, and proceed to store record into pojo.

```
if (usersRecord == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException("User with id " + id + " not found");
        }
User user = usersRecord.into(User.class);
```

Tested the endpoint like this:

```
http://localhost:7000/users/2
```

The server is now finally returning `NotFoundException`

```
{
"statusCode": 404,
"title": "Not Found",
"errorMessage": "The resource you're looking for cannot be found.",
"apiPath": "/users/2"
}
```